# android retrofit 2 есть проверка интернета?

Tags: android, retrofit

`Android retrofit 2` есть  проверка  интернета? (метод какой нибудь) просто каждый раз проверять таким образом как то не очень (((

```
  ConnectivityManager cm =
                (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
```

Comment: А зачем Вам нужна эта проверка? Может быть такая ситуация, что при проверке интернет будет, а уже при непосредственной работе с сетью – нет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для синхронных запросов.

```
Response<T> execute() throws IOException
```

То есть вам надо отлавливать IOException

```
try{
    syncCall.execute();
} catch (IOException e){
    обработка эксепшена
}
```

Для асинхронных надо переопределить метод onFailure

```
void onFailure(Call<T> call, Throwable t)
```

Как-то так

```
asyncCall.enqueue(new Callback<T>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<T> call, Response<T> response) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<T> call, Throwable t) {
        Обработка ошибки
    }
});
```

Comment: onFailure t.getMessage()  "Failed to connect to " показывает ошибку, когда нет интернета и когда сервер не доступен, поэтому не понятно как это ошибку различать

Comment: @Suleymanovtat если для вас действительно критично настолько тонко разбирать причину недоступности сервера для приложения, то можно в onFailure вставить вызов хелпера, в котором будут проверяться подробности